# Problemas con realtime

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un pequeño proyecto propio el cual es realizar una ruleta.
Mi problema es que en offline funciona perfectamente hasta que hay 2 usuarios o mas conectados ya que se duplican las tiradas y esas cosas . Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para que simplemente se ejecute la tirada en cada ventana de cada usuario y luego crear una tirada nueva y asi cada vez.

Comparto mi codigo.

```js
const ruleta = document.querySelector(".ruleta");
const hist = document.querySelector(".historial");
var p = document.querySelector("#p");
//ruleta.addEventListener("click" , gi); For TEST
//
//    function gi(){
//        calcular();
//        timer();
//    }
function timer(tirada, st) {
  //    if(iniciar=="1"){
  var a = tirada;
  var te = st;
  var id = setInterval(sum, 1000);

  function sum() {
    //if(st==1){ prep="Preparando: ";}
    //if(st==0){prep="Girando en ";}
    prep = "Preparando: "
    switch (true) {
      case te <= 20 && te > 15:
        p.innerHTML = prep + te;
        break;
      case te <= 15 && te >= 1:
        p.innerHTML = "Girando en " + te;
        break;
      case te < 1 && te >= 0:
        p.innerHTML = "Girando...";
        calcular(tirada);
        clearInterval(id);
        break;
    }
    te--;
    acttime(te);
  }
  //}else{
  //    p.innerHTML = "Conexion Erronea";
  //}
}

function acttime(value) {
  if (value <= 0) {
    value = 20;
  }
  cadena = "Tiempo=" + value;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/act.php",
    data: cadena,
    success: function(r) {}
  });

}

function hash(value, st) {
  if (value == 1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      mover = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+0 - +1500)) + +1500; //
      mover = mover + 5500;
      timer(mover, st);
      cadena = "Tirada=" + mover;
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/hash.php",
        data: cadena,
        success: function(r) {}
      });
    }, 5000)
  } else {}
}
//function puthash(){
//    
//}
function calcular(tirada) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    suit(tirada);
  }, 5100);
  ruleta.style.backgroundPositionX = "-" + tirada + "px";
}

function suit(value) {
  valor = parseInt(value);
  console.log(valor);
  setTimeout(function() {
    ruleta.style.backgroundPositionX = "-250px";
  }, 10000);
  switch (true) {
    case valor > 5500 && valor <= 5600:
      p.innerHTML = "Ganador : Rojo";
      rojo();
      break;
    case valor > 5600 && valor <= 5700:
      p.innerHTML = "Ganador : Negro";
      negro();
      break;
    case valor > 5700 && valor <= 5800:
      p.innerHTML = "Ganador : Rojo";
      rojo();
      break;
    case valor > 5800 && valor <= 5900:
      p.innerHTML = "Ganador : Negro";
      negro();
      break;
    case valor > 5900 && valor <= 6000:
      p.innerHTML = "Ganador : Rojo";
      rojo();
      break;
    case valor > 6000 && valor <= 6100:
      p.innerHTML = "Ganador : Negro";
      negro();
      break;
    case valor > 6100 && valor <= 6200:
      p.innerHTML = "Ganador : Rojo";
      rojo();
      break;
    case valor > 6200 && valor <= 6300:
      p.innerHTML = "Ganador Verde";
      verde();
      break;
    case valor > 6300 && valor <= 6400:
      p.innerHTML = "Ganador : Negro";
      negro();
      break;
    case valor > 6400 && valor <= 6500:
      p.innerHTML = "Ganador : Rojo";
      rojo();
      break;
    case valor > 6500 && valor <= 6600:
      p.innerHTML = "Ganador : Negro";
      negro();
      break;
    case valor > 6600 && valor <= 6700:
      p.innerHTML = "Ganador : Rojo";
      rojo();
      break;
    case valor > 6700 && valor <= 6800:
      p.innerHTML = "Ganador : Negro";
      negro();
      break;
    case valor > 6800 && valor <= 6900:
      p.innerHTML = "Ganador : Rojo";
      rojo();
      break;
    case valor > 6900 && valor <= 7000:
      p.innerHTML = "Ganador : Negro";
      negro();
      break;
  }
}

function rojo() {
  var div = document.createElement("DIV");
  div.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/rojo.png')";
  hist.appendChild(div);
  newgame();
}

function negro() {
  var div = document.createElement("DIV");
  div.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/negro.png')";
  hist.appendChild(div);
  newgame();
}

function verde() {
  var div = document.createElement("DIV");
  div.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/verde.png')";
  hist.appendChild(div);
  newgame();
}

function newgame() {
  mover = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+0 - +1500)) + +1500; //
  mover = mover + 5500;
  cadena = "Tirada=" + mover;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/mostrar.php",
    data: cadena,
    success: function(r) {}
  });
  timer(mover, 20);
}
```

```css
/*FONT*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5vh;
  display: block;
  background: #FF7F00;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

#left,
#right,
#body {
  display: block;
}

#left {
  width: 5%;
  height: 95vh;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #FF7F00;
  float: left;
}

#right {
  width: 15%;
  height: 95vh;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #FF7F00;
  float: right;
}

#body {
  vertical-align: top;
  /*    margin: auto 5px ;*/
  color: white;
  width: 80%;
  height: 95vh;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #03334e;
  /*    background-image: url("img/pp.jpg");*/
}

.body2 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 95vh;
  background: red;
}

.body2> {
  display: inline-block;
}

.ruleta {
  background-image: url(https://csgoatse.com/assets/www/img/gp/roulette.png);
  background-position: top;
  background-position-x: -250px;
  transition: all 5s;
  width: 100%;
  height: 115px;
}

.hijo {
  display: flex;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 5px solid #FF7F00;
  border-top: 5px solid #FF7F00;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.p {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto 5px;
}

#p {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.padre {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

#marca {
  height: 120px;
  min-height: 115px;
  width: 100%;
  top: -2px;
  left: 48.9%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: url(https://imgur.com/a/YEeb3Mu);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10000;
  transform: rotate3d(45deg);
  /*    border-radius: 0px 0px 16px 16px;*/
  /*    border: 1px solid #FF7F00;*/
  /*    opacity: 0.5;*/
}
```

```html
<?php 
$link = new mysqli("localhost","root","","csgo");
$query = $link->query("SELECT * FROM game")->fetch_assoc();
$var = $query['Tirada'];
$hash = $query['hash'];
?>
<!-- MOSTRAR PHP-->
<?php 
include('link.php');
//     TIEMPO
$tirada = $_POST['Tirada'];
//$tirada = "6500";
$hash = md5($tirada);
$link->query("UPDATE game set hash='$hash',Tirada='$tirada' where ID=1");
?>
<!-- ACT.PHP-->
<?php 

    include('link.php');
    $tiempo =$_POST['Tiempo'];
    $query = "UPDATE game set Tiempo='$tiempo'";
    $r = $link->query($query);
    $st = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r) ;

?>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- encabezado -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Titulo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ruleta.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/apuestas.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/perfil.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="timer(6500,20);">
  <!-- Cuerpo pagina -->
  <header>

    <div class="perf">
      Coins :<a id="balance">1000</a>
      <a></a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="body2">
    <div id="left">
    </div>
    <div id="body">
      <div class="padre">
        <div class="p">
          <p id="p">Conectando...</p>
          <p id="a">
            <?php echo $hash;?>
          </p>
          <p id="T"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
          <div class="ruleta">
            <div id="marca"></div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="historial">
        </div>
        <div class="apuestas">
          <div class="amount">
            <span>Coins</span>
            <input type="text" id="input">
            <button onclick="clear()">Borrar</button>
            <button onclick="sumar('10')">+10</button>
            <button onclick="sumar('100')">+100</button>
            <button onclick="sumar('1000')">+1000</button>
            <button onclick="dividir()">X1/2</button>
            <button onclick="multiplicar()">X2</button>
            <button onclick="min()">MIN</button>
            <button onclick="max()">MAX</button>
          </div>
          <div class="rojo" id="tipeapuesta">
            <button onclick="addstat('rojo')" id="bapuestas">Rojo x2</button>
            <div class="rstats" id="stats">

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="verde" id="tipeapuesta">
            <button onclick="addstat('verde')" id="bapuestas">Verde x14</button>
            <div class="vstats" id="stats">

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="negro" id="tipeapuesta">
            <button onclick="addstat('negro')" id="bapuestas">Negro x2</button>
            <div class="nstats" id="stats">

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">

    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.10.1/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ruleta.js"></script>
  <script src="js/stats1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

El problema es que por cada usuario que entra a la pagina de duplica la tirada y al final nunca están en la misma tirada simultanea ya que ejecuta el código javascript cada vez que alguien entra a la pagina pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo de esta misma manera con php ya que siempre creo que va a seguir ejecutando el código cada usuario. Las tiradas deberian das un numero del 5500 al 7000 y un tiempo de 20 segundos en el onload del body

Comment: Hola, a mime sucedió algo parecido, hace un tiempo cuando pasaba los datos de javascript a php que no me vaciaba el valor de la variable del  `$_POST` y la solución que encontrar fue colocar en la cabecera de mi script  el metodo `unset()` para borrar el valor de las variables donde guardaba el valor del `$_POST`.

Comment: @YoelRodriguez El problema creo que no es ese , Basicamente lo que quiero es que el codigo no se ejecute por cada persona en linea si no solo 1 vez por cada tirada :(

Comment: OK, mira si lo que quieres es que solo se ejecute el código php por cada tirada solo tienes que validarlo. Por lo que puedo ver tu recoges el valor del formulario en la variable  **$tirada** pues solo tienes que decir que si esta definida ejecutas el código sino no.